# mysql function for 2 rows (same name) with group by

Tags: mysql

I have my table:

```
id   name   salarry   month   year
1    mike   1000      1       2017
2    john   1200      1       2017
3    mike   1100      2       2017
4    mike   900       1       2017
```

my results now is:

```
id   name   sallary   month   year
2    john   1200      1       2017
1    mike   1100      1       2017
```

I want to show the sallary of mike separatelly by month:

```
id   name   sallary   month   year
1    mike   1000      1       2017
2    mike   1100      2       2017
3    john   1200      1       2017
```

the mysql code:

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `name` , MAX( sallary ) ,  `month` ,  `year` 
FROM  `test` 
GROUP BY  `name` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending from what You are looking for, it could be:

```
SELECT  MIN(`id`) as id,  `name` , MAX( sallary ) as salary ,  `month` ,  `year` 
FROM  `test` 
GROUP BY  `name` ,  `month` ,  `year`
```

or because mike have 2 salary in Jan 2017 (and of course it same Mike ;) ):

```
SELECT  MIN(`id`) as id,  `name` , SUM( sallary ) as salary ,  `month` ,  `year` 
FROM  `test` 
GROUP BY  `name` ,  `month` ,  `year`
```

because as unique identifier You choose Name - MIN(`id`) allow avoid errors when MySQL default settings - ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

**Specially for Rick James :)**

From original question, we can see -  id, can not be used as IDENTIFIER

so queries example with MIN and MAX for id - could be (and this realistic live scenario) - first or most resent contact with person

Before we go to next form of query - first we need decide mike(id=1) for Jan 17 and mike (id=4) for Jan 17, it is same person? and salary for Jan - it MAX or SUM (as I include in my examples).

Comment: thx mate this work perfect :D

Comment: The `id` provided will not necessarily be the one associated with the `salary` shown.  You have a variant of the [_groupwise max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem.

Comment: @RickJames - of course in THIS example id do not have any senses, but in more common case it could, so I just show how to proper select it. As mentioned in question - it possible (and good) exclude it from result. Plus I not include in answer example with JOIN (for select id exactly related for MAX salary) - again because question not cover this.

Comment: @a_vlad - The OP's query and both of your queries all have a potential mismatch of `id` and `salary`.  The problem is a subtle on because the `id` and `salary` _might_ match up, thereby leading the user to incorrectly assume that "all is well".  As indicated by his "this work perfect" Comment.

Comment: @RickJames - of course! it not a potential - it expected, as You can see I special point attention - uniques identifier is Name (and mike have 2 of them). We can go much deeper but it not asked. The author - just not use id really, for this reason for him - it was perfect